# Page redirects not working after Conversion to WAP

Tags: asp.net

I was able to successfully convert (really copy code over to a WAP project) a Web Site Project to a WAP project.

All is fine except after the site runs, any links are redirecting to page not found.  I'm trying to figure out why but it's not apparent.

So when you click on a link, does a handler play into effect?  What server-side variables kick in to handle the request?  I assume I would not look at a global.asax as that's really for application events.

so in our header for example here's a link:

```
<td class="HeaderLink"><a runat="server" id="Account">Account</a></td>
```

in the code-behind of the header control we set that link which simply sets it to an .aspx page as stated on our site.  Now the magic happening after the link is clicked is what I can't figure out or not magic but the problem.  These links have not been changed and were working fine in a non-WAP project.  The folder structure is the same.

Comment: Are they LinkButton controls? Hyperlink controls?  Plain old HTML anchors?  Are these redirects to pages on your site, or to external URLs?  Please post some example HTML and server-side code.

Comment: They are regular hyperlink tags.  The link has not changed.  This was working fine in an ASP.NET Web Site.  It simply links to http://oursite/somepage.aspx

Comment: Ok, so if I type it in, the same exact URL behind that example hyperlink and press enter, it can get to that page fine. It's only when I click to get to it via the hyperlink...same exact url!

Comment: so do hyperlinks post differently to the server in a WAP project vs. a Web Site or are handled differently on the server-side?

Comment: What path are you seeing in the URL when you get a page not found?  How does that path differ from what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that just by looking at your example that you're missing either the href="oursite/somepage.aspx" or the navigationURL="~/oursite/somepage.aspx" for the hyperlink that you're calling id="Account".

Comment: No, that's added dynamically to the <a> tag from code-behind...which is why you only see the id there.  It's there or I wouldn't be getting a url.  How it's being added and set from code-behind doesn't matter as I get a valid URL...the same URL that if typed in manually to the browser and you hit enter on your keyboard gets to the page fine with no errors.  Again, it's when I click the url (I first hover over it and I see it's definitely that same url) that I get a page not found after I click it.